# Не работатет авторизация PHP

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, pdo, авторизация, регистрация

Ecть вот такой код системы авторизации на сайте и я не совсем понимаю почему он не работает.

```
function loginUser($mysqli, $login, $pass)
{
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login=? or pass=?"); 
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $login, $pass);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    return $result->fetch_assoc();
}
if ($Module == 'login' and isset($_POST['enter'])) {
    $auth = loginUser($mysqli, $_POST['login'], $_POST['pass']);
    if (!$_POST['login'] or !$_POST['pass']) {
        echo '<script>alert('Невозможно обработать форму')</script>';
    }
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login=?"); 
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $login, $pass);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $user = $result->fetch_assoc();
    if ($user && password_verify($_POST['pass'], $user['pass'])) {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
        header('Location: /');
        exit();
    } else {
        echo '<script>alert('Невозможно обработать форму')</script>';
    }
}
```

Ошибок никаких нет, просто обновляется страница и всё. Подскажите пожалуйста в чём дело?

Comment: Как минимум я вижу некорректное использование кавычек. А за подробностями - в лог ошибок.

Comment: Плюс код у Вас дублируется: сначала вы выполняете запрос к базе данных в функции loginUser(), а затем, с небольшими изменениями, после вызова этой функции. Плюс отсутствует проверка входящих данных (но это уже придирки пошли). Включите отображение ошибок, пользуйте var_dump().